# Does the alignment problem cause uneven tread wear in my case?

Tags: toyota, tires, camry, alignment, wear

2002 Camry LE, 4 cylinder, Michelin premier a/s performance h/v purchased in 2017, 60,000 mile tread wear warranty. The tread reaches the end of the life only after 33,000 miles, and the tread wear is uneven, i.e. outer tread worn more than the inner one. In contrast, the tread wear is even on my other car. Is the alignment the only cause for the excessive and uneven tread wear in my case? I’m really doubting. If not, what shall I check as the next step?

Here are the details. The outer most groove depths are 1/32” (front tires) and 2/32” (rear tires), and the inner ones are 3/32” and 4/32”. I found the car pulled slightly to the left on highway in 9/2020, and had the front wheels aligned, but the problem remained until at least 6/2021. The last 10,000 miles are mostly short trips less than 6 miles, but before that the trips were usually around 17 miles. The maintenance record is as follows, and the center column is the mileage.

- 5/10/2015 unknown Adjust headlight. Replace right front lower control arm with ball joint, transmission mount and left tag light. Not sure whether the transmission mount or the torque strut mount replaced. On service note and suggestions, it is the torque strut mount, but transmission mount was purchased on receipt.
- 5/11/2015 unknown Replace front brake pad and rotor
- 11/12/2015 110154 Alignment
- 5/7/2016 115581 Oil change. Right front sway bar bracket is broken and the bushing is missing. Right side tag light bulb is out.
- 5/8/2016 unknown Replace right front sway bar bracket, bushing and right side tag light bulb
- *3/7/2017 124002 4 new tires*
- 11/1/2017 130406 Tire rotation
- 10/20/2018 140363 Tire rotation
- 10/12/2019 147860 Tire rotation
- 9/25/2020 unknown Front wheel alignment due to car pull. Road test vehicle. Check all suspension and steering parts for wear. Check tire pressure and condition. Check riding height. Check caster and camber angles and adjust as required. Check and set toe-in as required. Center steering wheel.
- 1/30/2023 157068 4 new tires
- 2/2/2023 157108 Alignment check, not adjustment was performed, thus please ignore the “Actual” column
  [image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "uneven tread wear"? Are different tires wearing differently? If so, how? Are all the tires wearing at the same rate, but the wear across a single tire is not equal? (e.g. tire is worn more on the inside than the outside) Please be specific.

Comment: tire is worn more on the outside than the inside. I will edit my post right now.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Seems no one interested...